# React Native FlatList filter with buttons

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-flatlist

I need little help. Im trying to filter and then re-render the data/list with some buttons. I'm using a Redux for the data to be get.

Here is the default flatlist what im showing when the screen is open.

```
const { data } = this.props.data; // Redux data

return (
  <View>
    <View>
      <Text>The list..</Text>
    </View>
    <FlatList
      data={data.filter(item => item.outcome == null)}
      keyExtractor={item => item.signal_id.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <ListTips
          key={item.signal_id}
          competition={item.league}
          event={item.event}
          sport={item.sport}
          outcome={item.outcome}
          date={Moment(item.start_date).startOf("hour").fromNow()}
        />
      )}
    />
  </View>
);
```

And this is showing a list with Sports events and outcome of the event. I want to create a 3-4 buttons/touchable elements so I can filter the sport(item.sport.toLowerCase() == 'handball') and the list to be refresh only with Handball sports events.

I have a data for handball events of 200 and whole data is 1200, football is 400 so i click on the next button to the handball for the football, to show the list only for football.

I tried to limit the data by calling this.props.getData() from action.js from the Redux but it load the whole data again.

Basic: i want with onPress element (touchableopacity to change the data (data={data.filter(item => item.outcome == null)}) to data={data.filter(item => item.sport == 'football')} for example and load only football events.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I am not going to make an answer because it will be to complexe for a single stackoverflow thread. I made a fiddle that answer to "how to filter data in redux" (in your context): https://jsfiddle.net/ozut9arn/1. I hope it will help you, because your are facing a complex problem.